# Snap to own mesh

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, snapping

I know this is possible and I have probably activated something by mistake and now I can't figure how to reverse it.

When I use the "snap during transform" it only snaps to vertexes/lines/faces in other meshes than the one I'm editing.

How can I make it snap to vertices/lines/faces within the same mesh I'm editing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable *Snap onto self* in *3D view > header*:

[image]

Comment: I knew it was simple... :P Since "Limit selection to visible" and "snap onto self" have the same symbol I got them mixed up... Thanks.